# Leaflet Map Marker Issue - R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am having some issues with my leaflet markers. I have made a handful of leaflet maps before, but this [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfRdz.png) has never happened before. The markers are appearing but on the South Pole!
The coordinates in my [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgij7.png) are definitely not, however. They should be scattered across Michigan. My code is quite simple and is in the UI of my app.

```
leaflet(fac_map_data) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers())
```

This same code template is the one on Leaflets documentation and I have made multiple maps like this before with similar data. Not sure why this is happening!

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), instead of linking to your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like things are plotting near the south pole because -85 latitude is pretty near the south pole (-90 latitude).

Maybe you transposed latitude & longitiude? That would lead to points near Grand Rapids, MI.